# subversion authentication with sharpsvn driver

Tags: c#, svn, authentication, sharpsvn

I've set up my subversion server following the steps on : http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html

The server is running on my localhost

**Configurations**

this is my config file:

```
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
authz-db = authz
```

authz:

```
[/]
* = w
```

passwd:

```
[users]
plorio = pass
test = pass
```

**Code using sharpSvn driver**

```
var svn = new SvnClient();
svnClient.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new NetworkCredential("test",
                                                                    "pass",
                                                                     new Uri("svn://localhost/main").AbsoluteUri);

var localFilename = "C:\\testFile.txt";
var commitArgs = new SvnCommitArgs();
commitArgs.LogMessage = "test";
svn.Commit(localFilename, commitArgs); // <<< error:
```

**Error**

svn.Commit(localFilename, commitArgs); gives the following error:

Commit failed (details follow):

- innerException : `{"Authentication error from server: Username not found"}`
- SvnErrorCode : `SharpSvn.SvnErrorCode.SVN_ERR_RA_NOT_AUTHORIZED`
- SubversionErrorCode : `170001`
- StackTrace :

  at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, SvnException error) in f:\qqn\sharpsvn-dist-1.6\src\sharpsvn\svnclientargs.cpp:line 76
     at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, svn_error_t* error) in f:\qqn\sharpsvn-dist-1.6\src\sharpsvn\svnclientargs.cpp:line 42
     at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Commit(ICollection`1 paths, SvnCommitArgs args, SvnCommitResult& result) in f:\qqn\sharpsvn-dist-1.6\src\sharpsvn\commands\commit.cpp:line 136
     at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Commit(String path, SvnCommitArgs args) in f:\qqn\sharpsvn-dist-1.6\src\sharpsvn\commands\commit.cpp:line 74
     at Zephyr.OnDemand.WorkbookManagementService.WorkbookManagementOperations.UpdateWorkbook(String client, ManagedWorkbookDetails details, Stream content) in C:\src\zod\ci-tests\SVN\WorkbookManagementService\WorkbookManagementOperations.cs:line 165
     at SVN.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\src\zod\ci-tests\SVN\Program.cs:line 24
     at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
     at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

I am fairly confident the error exists in the subversion configuration or the `svnClient.Authentication.DefaultCredentials` if anyone has any ideas it would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**
I was copying over my working directory from another Subversion working directory. This was problematic because I was also copied over the .svn folders. This caused the program to try and commit to the server defined in the .svn folder, which rendered the authentication error.

**Solution**
Delete .svn folders from working directory and re add and commit files